# Creating an IntelliJ Module Programmatically

Tags: intellij-idea, module, kotlin

I'm trying to make a proper project, like the one setup when you go through the Kotlin wizard or something, but I can't figure it out.

```
class SpigotKtWizard : ModuleBuilder() {

override fun setupRootModel(modifiableRootModel: ModifiableRootModel?) {}

override fun getModuleType(): ModuleType<*> {
    return SpigotKtModuleType.instance
}

override fun createWizardSteps(wizardContext: WizardContext, modulesProvider: ModulesProvider): Array<ModuleWizardStep> {
    return arrayOf(BuildOptionsStep())
}

override fun createProject(name: String?, path: String?): Project? {
    val project = super.createProject(name, path) ?: return null
    val d = project.baseDir.createChildData(this, "Test")
    File(d.path).writeText("Testing boyyyy")
    return project
}
```

}

This is what I have currently, and I'm getting this:

[image]

But other projects (and specifically, the same design I'm trying to achieve), look more like this:

[image]

Is there a page in the docs that I missed?

Answer (score 2):

In pic 2 you're displaying a "project" instead of a "module", see [the offical doc](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/project_model/project.html).

You may want to implement a `DirectoryProjectGeneratorBase<YourSettingsBean>` and register a (as an example you may refer to [this file my julia plugin](https://github.com/ice1000/julia-intellij/blob/master/src/org/ice1000/julia/lang/module/julia-projects.kt)) `directoryProjectGenerator` in plugin.xml.

In your implementation of `generateProject`, you can create files, set files as source root/test root/excluded root by using:

```
    ApplicationManager.getApplication().runWriteAction {
        val modifiableModel: ModifiableRootModel = ModifiableModelsProvider.SERVICE.getInstance().getModuleModifiableModel(module)
        module.rootManager.modifiableModel.apply {
            inheritSdk()
            contentEntries.firstOrNull()?.apply {
                addExcludeFolder(findOrCreate(baseDir, "out", module))
                addSourceFolder(findOrCreate(baseDir, "src", module), false)
            }
            commit()
        }
        ModifiableModelsProvider.SERVICE.getInstance().commitModuleModifiableModel(modifiableModel)
    }
```

This should be missing in the doc, BTW. So it's not your fault. But I recommend you to take a look at the existing plugin projects (like the julia plugin mentioned above, [the mathemetica plugin](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-IntelliJ-Plugin) or [the covscript plugin](https://github.com/covscript/covscript-intellij)), which are extremely helpful for new comers.